# type error : object is not a function Backbone.js

Tags: function, object, backbone.js, typeerror, uncaught-exception

I get this uncaught type error of object is not a function when trying to write a collection view. I have used the same code while doing the App but as am re doing the app with require.js, I get this error. Please help me. Here is the code :

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  // Sub Views
  'view/todo_view'
],function(
  _,
  Backbone,
  // Sub Views
  TodoView
){
    return Backbone.View.extend({
      el:$('#todos'),

      render: function(){
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne,this);
        return this;
      },

      addOne: function(todoIt1){            
        var todoView = new TodoView({
          model: todoIt1
        });
        this.$el.append(todoView.render().el);
      }

    });

  });
```

Comment: Please, add a error message with stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

This kind of error happens when using the operator `new` with an object, and not a function. You should check if `TodoView` really is a function, and not an instance of `TodoView`. If that's the case, make sure you didn't misplace a `new` operator in your `TodoView` file.